# unreadable quickcheck log file after a test routine

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, cabal, quickcheck

I made a test routine for a Haskell program with quickcheck. I declared it in my cabal file with :

```
Test-Suite routine_de_test
  Type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Hs-Source-Dirs:     test
  Main-is:            Tests.hs
```

and launched it with :

```
cabal configure --enable-tests
cabal buil
cabal test
```

The tests are processed correctly and I was expecting to see details about the random value used for each test in the log file `dist/test/` but when I open it, the file looks like this :

[image]

I tried to open the file with several encoding (UTF8, ISO-8859-15, ...) but nothing is changed.

Is it normal? Or is there something wrong?

**Is it possible when performing quickcheck test from cabal to get the complete list of random values used for each tests?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the funny characters are simply backspaces, and quickcheck is simply reporting the number of tests it has performed so far by overwriting `(0 tests)` with `(1 test)` and then `(2 tests)` and then with `(3 tests)`, etc.

Visually it will look fine when displayed to a terminal.

Update:

To report the random values used for a test the only way I know of is to write your test to explicitly display (or save to a file) the values used.

If your test is a pure function you can use the `trace` function from  `Debug.Trace`. For instance, if you have this property:

```
prop_commutes :: Int -> Int -> Bool
prop_commutes a b = a + b == b + a
```

You can trace each invocation of `prop_commutes` by modifying like this:

```
import Debug.Trace

prop_commutes :: Int -> Int -> Bool
prop_commutes x y = a + b == b + a
  where (a,b) = trace ("(a,b) = " ++ show (x,y)) (x,y)
```

and then `quickCheck prop_commutes` will emit lines like:

```
(x,y) = (20,-73)
(x,y) = (71,-36)
(x,y) = (2,-11)
...
```

in addition to its normal output.

Comment: exactly - you'll get the same if you use ghci say in emacs ;)